# How to compile C++ code using C#. Need to develop a C++ IDE

Tags: c#, c++, gcc, compiler-construction

I am interested in developing C++ IDE, but for ease and better UI, I want to develop the IDE using C#. But I am stuck with a problem that I cant find how to compile the C++ code using C# and build the ".exe" of C++ program that was compiled using my IDE. Can anyone please suggest me if their is any API or Library that can Build the ".exe" of any C++ code that I give input.

I am able to compile and build C# code, but can anyone please help me if there is a way that i can integrate the c++ compiler feature in my application.
What i need is something similar to CSharpCodeProvider but for compiling C++ code.

What i m doing for C# compiling is in the code below.

```
class Compiler
{
    public static bool CompileFromSource(string source, string Output, string Icon = null, string[] Resources = null)
    {
        // We declare the new compiler parameters variable
        // that will contain all settings for the compilation.
        CompilerParameters CParams = new CompilerParameters();

        // We want an executable file on disk.
        CParams.GenerateExecutable = true;
        // This is where the compiled file will be saved into.
        CParams.OutputAssembly = Output;

        // We need these compiler options, we will use code optimization,
        // compile as a x86 process and our target is a windows form.
        // The unsafe keyword is used because the stub contains pointers and
        // unsafe blocks of code.
        string options = "/optimize+ /platform:x86 /target:winexe /unsafe";
        // If the icon is not null (as we initialize it), add the corresponding option.
        if (Icon != null)
            options += " /win32icon:\"" + Icon + "\"";

        // Set the options.
        CParams.CompilerOptions = options;
        // We don't care about warnings, we don't need them to show as errors.
        CParams.TreatWarningsAsErrors = false;

        // Add the references to the libraries we use so we can have access
        // to their namespaces.
        CParams.ReferencedAssemblies.Add("System.dll");
        CParams.ReferencedAssemblies.Add("System.Windows.Forms.dll");
        CParams.ReferencedAssemblies.Add("System.Drawing.dll");
        CParams.ReferencedAssemblies.Add("System.Data.dll");
        CParams.ReferencedAssemblies.Add("Microsoft.VisualBasic.dll");

        // Check if the user specified any resource files.
        // If yes, add then to the stub's resources.
        if (Resources != null && Resources.Length > 0)
        {
            // Loop through all resource files specified in the Resources[] array.
            foreach (string res in Resources)
            {
                // Add each resource file to the compiled stub.
                CParams.EmbeddedResources.Add(res);
            }
        }

        // Dictionary variable is used to tell the compiler that we want
        // our file to be compiled for .NET v2
        Dictionary<string, string> ProviderOptions = new Dictionary<string, string>();
        ProviderOptions.Add("CompilerVersion", "v2.0");

        // Now, we compile the code and get the result back in the "Results" variable
        CompilerResults Results = new CSharpCodeProvider(ProviderOptions).CompileAssemblyFromSource(CParams, source);

        // Check if any errors occured while compiling.
        if (Results.Errors.Count > 0)
        {
            // Errors occured, notify the user.
            MessageBox.Show(string.Format("The compiler has encountered {0} errors",
                Results.Errors.Count), "Errors while compiling", MessageBoxButtons.OK,
                MessageBoxIcon.Error);

            // Now loop through all errors and show them to the user.
            foreach (CompilerError Err in Results.Errors)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(string.Format("{0}\nLine: {1} - Column: {2}\nFile: {3}", Err.ErrorText,
                    Err.Line, Err.Column, Err.FileName), "Error",
                    MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
            }
            return false;

        }
        else
        {
            // No error was found, return true.
            return true;
        }

    }
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: I guess you could always wrap libclang in a DLL

Comment: See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms235639.aspx. But I think this task is much more complex than you would think :) (See make files...)

Comment: @Mgetz , I didnt get what you are saying. Can you please explain a bit. Thanks :)

Comment: Clang++ is a compiler frontend for clang a C++ compiler. If you want to use a compiler as a service I would recommend wrapping libclang which is the actual compiler in a DLL you can P/Invoke to. http://clang.llvm.org/

Comment: @qqbenq , What you suggested will be possible when your system will have gcc, or c++ compiler. But i want to integrate compiler feature in my IDE, i.e it should not use any other program to compile other than my IDE. I would be grateful if you can suggest me something more :) Thanks.

Comment: @SaqibVohra: Then it isn´t a normal IDE. Any sane software out there separates IDE and compiler, and that is for a lot of very good reasons. Other than that, you´re asking us how to write a full-featured C++-compiler from scratch, without any idea or specific question? -1 from me.

Comment: @deviantfan , I think you got my question wrong. I just want to build an ".exe" of the c++ code provided using my C# program. I want to use some existing C++ compiler like gcc, but I dont know how to do that. I know the difference between Compiler and IDE very well, but I apologize if I cant explain you my question properly.

Comment: Your last two commonets are conflicting each other "[But i want to integrate compiler feature in my IDE, i.e it should not use any other program to compile other than my IDE](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23543134/how-to-compiler-c-code-using-c-need-to-develop-a-c-ide#comment36119803_23543134)" and "[I want to use some existing C++ compiler like gcc](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23543134/how-to-compiler-c-code-using-c-need-to-develop-a-c-ide#comment36120146_23543134)", so which is it?

Comment: @Mgetz, Thanks I am looking into it :) Will Clang++ compiler (i.e libclang.dll) will deploy with my C# program and build an ".exe" of the C++ code i will provide? and I will be thankful if you can provide me any tutorial or explanation on how can I do that, because I cant find relevant resources on Google. Thanks :)

Comment: Looking at your example code I think I now understand what you are looking for. Are you looking for a library or class that inherits from [`System.CodeDom.Compiler`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/system.codedom.compiler.codedomprovider) that provides a C++/x86 compiler similar to the `CSharpCodeProvider` and `VBCodeProvider` already do in the .NET framework? Some kind of `CppCodeProvider`?

Comment: @ScottChamberlain, I am extremely sorry for making the conflicting statements. I actually mean that I want to deploy a compiler like gcc etc (existing Compiler) in my C# Program(i.e IDE), It should compile the code using the deployed compiler in my IDE. It should work without any compiler installed in the System, It should not use any program other than my IDE that has deployed compiler in it. Hope  I made the statement clear. Thanks :)

Comment: @ScottChamberlain, Yes exactly. I want to know about some class or library that could compile the C++ code like CSharpCodeProvider, but the compiled code i.e ".exe" should not require any dependencies like .Net framework to execute and CSharpProvider compiled code require.

Comment: After a long digging, I found that Compilation of CPP is not supported by Microsoft Currently. You can use any C++ Compiler that supports command line (gcc, Mingw etc.) for this purpose. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

While not in .NET it self when you install Visual Studio or install the Windows SDK it will install the assembly CppCodeProvider.dll in to the GAC which includes the [`CppCodeProvider`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualc.cppcodeprovider%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) class.

However I don't know how easily it will be to deploy, you may need to include the CppCodeProvider.dll in with your class when you deploy it and any other dll's you find that it depends on.

Comment: Thanks alot :) But i still want to know that the ".exe" of the compiled C++ code will require .net to run or not?

Comment: No, it would not require .net, it may or my not require the C++ Runtime to be installed depending on your compliation options, but it would not require .net.

Comment: I tried alot to use CppCodeProvider, but cant do it properly because documentation is not provided properly any where. Can you please guide me Scott. I tried few implementation, but cant achieve success.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23553159/how-to-compile-c-code-using-cppcodeprovider-in-c-sharp

Comment: I have never used it, I have no guidance on this issue.

Comment: well ok, np :) Thanks

Comment: After a long digging, I found that Compilation of CPP is not supported by Microsoft Currently. You can use any C++ Compiler that supports command line for this issue. Thanks :)