# How do I handle the error not implemented Exception was unhandled in cppcodeprovider

Tags: winforms

This exception indicates on the line of the code
CodeDomProvider = cpp.CreateCompiler();

And he says
The method or operation is not implemented

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I5v76.jpg)

my code is

```
CppCodeProvider cpp = new CppCodeProvider();
                CodeDomProvider.IsDefinedLanguage("Cpp");
                CodeDomProvider.CreateProvider("cpp");
            
                ICodeCompiler IC = cpp.CreateCompiler();
                string Output = "Out.exe";
                Button ButtonObject = (Button)sender;

                textBox2.Text = "";


            
                CompilerParameters parameters = new CompilerParameters();
                parameters.GenerateExecutable = true;
                parameters.OutputAssembly = Output;
                
                CompilerResults results = IC.CompileAssemblyFromSource(parameters, textBox1.Text);

                if (results.Errors.Count > 0)
                {
                    foreach (CompilerError CompErr in results.Errors)
                    {
                        textBox2.Text = textBox2.Text +
                            "Line number " + CompErr.Line +
                            ", Error Number: " + CompErr.ErrorNumber +
                            ", '" + CompErr.ErrorText + ";" +
                            Environment.NewLine + Environment.NewLine;
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    //Successful Compile
                    textBox2.ForeColor = Color.Blue;
                    textBox2.Text = "Success!";
                    //If we clicked run then launch our EXE
                    if (ButtonObject.Text == "Run") Process.Start(Output);
                }
```

Answer (score 0):

In short, as I said in the comment, a *Method or Operation Not Implemented* exception normally occurs when you have a method that's been added, but no implementation has been placed in the method.  This normally occurs when you generate a method using IntelliSense, and is the compilers way of telling you "Hey, you need to put something in here".

```
public void MyMethod()
{
    throw new NotImplementedException();
}
```

Adding an implementation to the method or even commenting the throwing of the exception would resolve the issue here.

```
public void MyMethod()
{
    //throw new NotImplementedException();
}
```

Having said that I know that the method throwing the issue isn't your code, that was more so you understand **WHAT** the error is telling you.

I think the way you're trying to do what you're doing may not be correct.  After doing some research and looking at the [MS Learn Page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.codedom.compiler.codedomprovider.createcompiler?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.8#System_CodeDom_Compiler_CodeDomProvider_CreateCompiler) you'll notice that this is *Obsolete* and has been since .net Framework 2.0.

See a similar thread on SO about this topic: [How to compile C++ Code using CppCodeProvider in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23553760/4990925)